# Jupyter on EC2: SSL Error

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to serve a Jupyter notebook from EC2 but I'm getting an SSL error.
I'm using this AMI: `TensorFlow GPU - @nottombrown (ami-8ed4d0e4)`. I used a self-signed certificate and that might be part of the problem.

I've looked at several other SO posts that have a similar error such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833642/python-apns-sslerror), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790627/ssl-error-while-implementing-apple-push-notification) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror), but they're getting the error in a quite different context and I can't figure out how to get the solutions (such as setting `verify=False`) to work for me.

```
[E 15:52:44.954 NotebookApp] Exception in callback (<socket._socketobject object at 0x7f5f993dad00>, <function null_wrapper at 0x7f5f99319758>)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 883, in start
        handler_func(fd_obj, events)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 274, in accept_handler
        callback(connection, address)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 239, in _handle_connection
        do_handshake_on_connect=False)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 521, in ssl_wrap_socket
        return ssl.wrap_socket(socket, **dict(context, **kwargs))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
        ciphers=ciphers)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in __init__
        ciphers)
    SSLError: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This error means that the SSL certificate can't be found.**

**If you haven't yet created an SSL certificate:**

Create one by typing the following into the command line (starting at your home directory):

```
$ mkdir certs
$ cd certs
$ sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

(from [these instructions](http://blog.impiyush.me/2015/02/running-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws.html))

**Now that you have an SSL certificate:**

You need to tell Jupyter where to find it.

Take a look at `jupyter_notebook_config.py` if you have one (or generate one using `jupyter notebook --generate-config`).

Make sure that you have the following line:

`c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file`

(see [the Jupyter Notebook docs](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html?highlight=ssl))

and make sure that your self-signed SSL certificate is actually at that location. A common mistake is to mix up `certs` with `.certs` for example. A mistake like this will result in Jupyter not being able to find your SSL certificate and that'll result in the error that you're getting.

Comment: Still getting [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:645)

Comment: @yuchien were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: i am have the same issue, ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:4022), i am sure i have done the sudo thing you mentioned, and i have this line: c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' #location of your certificate file

Answer (score 12):

Try to add https:// to force web browser to use HTTPS-connection.

I got:

```
[W 08:25:56.148 NotebookApp] SSL Error on 9 ('<jupyter-server-ip>', 62862): [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:590)
```

because Chrome tried to use HTTP connection. When using

```
https://<jupyter-server-ip>
```

it finally works :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the permission issue is occurring because the mycert.pem file has only root permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 20 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 20 12:09 ..
-rw------- 1 root   root   2949 Mar 20 12:22 mycert.pem
```

I could not run jupyter notebook as root therefore i chowned the permissions

```
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu mycert.pem
```

this solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a the same error while running jupyter notebook as a public server with a self-signed cert under Unbuntu 14.4.  In my case, the problem was due to an error in the jupyter_notebook_config.py file.  I had incorrectly set  **c.NotebookApp.client_ca = u'/../mycert.pem'**.  Commenting this line out solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This error comes because to two reasons:

1. Certificate Issue

```
$ mkdir certs
$ cd certs
$ sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

2. Wrong http(s) call.

   - `https://ec2-ip:8888` | use http**s**
   - To get ec2-ip
     `curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com`

Comment: what is the difference between rsa:2048 and rsa:1024?