# Can not access files uploaded to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am not sure if this post should be posted here on Server Fault site, but I saw some posts about AWS here on Stack Overflow, so I hope this one fits here too.

I got the following problem when zipping and uploading files written in Python and Windows 10 not Ubuntu to AWS lambda function:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied

I tried chmod 644 on files before zipping them, but I still have the same issue. All files that I upload to AWS through zipping will have permission denied issue, any solution?

I checked as well other posts about this where they discussed using chmod on files before zipping them, but I got the same problem as well:

- Post 1: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3235
- Post 2: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=742422
- Post 3: [PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when accessing to aws ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097180/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when) accessing-to-aws-ec2

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you creating the files? In AWS Lambda you can only create files in `/tmp/`.

Comment: When you say "zipping and uploading files ... to the aws lambda function", do you mean from your local computer to the lambda function as the source code for the lambda, or something else? What are you using to upload the zip file, the aws cli or something else?