# SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:4022) on Ubuntu when starting jupyter notebook

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, permissions

I have this problem when I am trying to initiate my Jupyter Notebook in Ubuntu over the EC2 server.

> SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:4022)

Originally I had the

> permission error [Errno 13]

then I followed this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097180/permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-accessing-to-aws-ec2) and fixed it by changing the ownership of the `/home` folder and `~/.local/share/jupyter/` folder to current user.

Now I have the SSL issue. I checked out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387654/jupyter-on-ec2-ssl-error) as suggested, but no luck.

I then `cd` to my certs folder, the `"mycert.pem"` is there. And I am sure I replace the local host IP address with `"https://" amazon url`.

My error code seems not similar to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level) too, though we both have key too small. But mine is `"ee key "`, and `"_ssl.c:4022"`, which is different from them.

The entire error message is like this:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-15-155:~$ jupyter notebook
[I 16:53:35.24 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/ubuntu
[I 16:53:35.24 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.0 is running at:
[I 16:53:35.24 NotebookApp] https://ip-172-31-15-155:8888/?token=5d6f7e3d198847e0b9008cff94deb68355701d6c6c983322
[I 16:53:35.24 NotebookApp]  or https://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=5d6f7e3d198847e0b9008cff94deb68355701d6c6c983322
[I 16:53:35.25 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:53:35.28 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/ubuntu/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-22585-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        https://ip-172-31-15-155:8888/?token=5d6f7e3d198847e0b9008cff94deb68355701d6c6c983322
     or https://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=5d6f7e3d198847e0b9008cff94deb68355701d6c6c983322
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(4, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(4, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 189, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 276, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 288, in _handle_connection
    connection = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 608, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 576, in ssl_options_to_context
    context.load_cert_chain(
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:4022)
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(4, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(4, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 189, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 276, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 288, in _handle_connection
    connection = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 608, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 576, in ssl_options_to_context
    context.load_cert_chain(
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: EE_KEY_TOO_SMALL] ee key too small (_ssl.c:4022)
```

Comment: is it related to the rsa:1024 in "sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem" ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

cd to your cert folder, and type this command:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
```

You are right, increase your rsa to 2048, this will solve your problem. At least this solved mine.

Comment: What does it do? Replace the certificate? Where should the certificates be? Is "sudo" required?

Comment: Also, should it be `-keyout mycert.key` instead?

Comment: It depends on what other settings are used, but the important part was to use `2048` for the encryption size, rather than a default or whatever smaller size was in use before.

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong nice catch! worked like a charm on my side

Comment: this caused me SSL: error:05800074:x509 certificate routines::key values mismatch

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a .pfx file from the client so generating a new key was not an option for me, the key size was 1024 bits but python versions 3.10+ demands that the key size must be greater than 2048 bits, so as a workaround I had to downgrade to python 3.9.1 to solve the key size error ...