# Problem with permission accessing AWS EC2 instance from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions, jupyter-notebook

I've successfully setup an instance in AWS EC2 and run jupyter notebook. I then tried to access it from my local machine using the public domain, such as https://ec2-18-217-220-13.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888/ but I get a message "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" from my EC2 server screen. What is wrong? FYI I've followed this setup guide:

https://chrisalbon.com/aws/basics/run_project_jupyter_on_amazon_ec2/

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errno 13 is a timeout error which is usually because the security groups are not properly set.

Make sure you have set your security group to accept inbound traffic on port 8888.

Go to EC2, and select "Security Groups" on the right hand side

1. Select the inbound security group for your instance
2. Click on the "Inbound" tab
3. Click "Edit"
4. Click "Add Rule"
5. In "Type" select "Custom TCP Rule"
6. In "Port Range" enter "8888"
7. In "Source" select "My IP" if you want it only accessible from your current IP, or "Anywhere" if you want it accessible from anywhere
8. Finally, select "Save"

You should now be able to access the instance on port 8888.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but in EC2 it’s already setup like that  from the beginning. Is there anything else I have to check?

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions to see if it helps:

Changed the ownership of the **/home** folder and **~/.local/share/jupyter/** folder to current user running this command:

**sudo chown -R $USER /home/

sudo chown -R $USER ~/.local/share/jupyter/**

If you encounter ssl error problem, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387654/jupyter-on-ec2-ssl-error).

Make sure you type https:// in your browser instead of http://.

If you have Your connection is not private problem in your chrome and can not proceed, try safari or other browsers. This happens in chrome with version 70 or newer.
And turn on ***port 8888*** for your instance by selecting ingress rule and there add port.