gcloud bigquery client connection - ssl error - disable ssl
I was trying to connect my jupyter notebook to google cloud bigquery for running some queries.
I was facing ssl error while connecting with
gcloud auth application-default login which i was able to resolve with
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation  True
But after that when i was trying to run a query in bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery 
client = bigquery.Client() ....
using the python client for bigquery i am getting the same SSL error.
Why am i getting the ssl error again even though i disabled it. Is there any way i can disable the SSL validation specifically for python big query client?
A solution to disable ssl validation for python big query client.

When you say that you are connecting to Google Cloud BigQuery from your Jupyter notebook, can we delve into WHERE your notebook is running?  Is it on your local PC, on a Google Cloud Compute Engine or one of the many managed Jupyter notebook environments available from Google?

from my local PC

Is there more error text than "ssl error" .... I'm looking here .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387654/jupyter-on-ec2-ssl-error
